# Marginal probability density function of $f_Y(y)$ knowing the joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$ and its domain

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this task, where I have to find the density function, but I'm totally lost.

The task is:

Let $(X,Y)$ be an absolutely continuous $2$-dimensional random vector with density function $f(x,y)$ defined as:

$f(x,y) = 4\,x$ if $y$ is between $0$ and $x^2,$ and $x$ is between $0$ and $1.$
Zero else.

Then I have to find the density function $f(y)$ of $Y$, for all $y \in \mathbb R$ (real numbers).

---

These would be the drawings associated with the OP:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If we have a joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of the random vector $(X,Y)$, we can obtain the marginal density function by integrating one of the variables of the joint density function out, i.e.
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx.
$$
We have that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=4x$ if $0\le y\le x^2$ and $0\le x\le1$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ otherwise. The first condition is equivalent to the condition $0\le y\le1$ and $\sqrt y\le x\le1$, which makes the integral easier to calculate. Hence,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\int_{\sqrt y}^14xdx=2(1-y)
$$
for $0\le y\le1 $ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise.